# powerbuilder11.5 autocommit=true doesn't work, transaction rolledback

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm upgrading PowerBuilder 9.0 to Version 11.5

Used to work with autocommit=true, but in PowerBuilder11.5:

When using autocommit=true, I get error connecting, sqlstate 42000, dbcode 3997
(MARS problem).
Have done some reading, and so added this to DBPARM:
ProviderString='MARS Connection=FALSE;'

Now the connection works, BUT:
the transaction is not committed, and when exiting program, it's all rolled back...

This is the code:
(For security reasons I've masked the user IDs and so forth with ###'s ..)

```
    SQLCA.DBMS = "SNC SQL Native Client(OLE DB)"
    SQLCA.LogPass = "######"
    SQLCA.ServerName = "#######"
    SQLCA.LogId = "######"
    SQLCA.AutoCommit = True
```

SQLCA.DBParm= "Database='yedidtst',Provider='SQLNCLI10',ProviderString='MARS Connection=FALSE;"

```
    Connect;

    string  scommand="begin transaction"


execute immediate :scommand;

execute immediate "INSERT INTO [######].[dbo].[app_application]      ([application])  VALUES  ('stam2')";


commit;
```

### // execute immediate "end transaction";

The transaction is not performed, it's rolledBack and nothing gets done,
even when I added the line with  "end transaction" .

What is wrong here ?

Thanks,
Ronit.

Comment: WE solved the issue yesterday using this:
We added this line to DBParm:
            ProviderString='MARS Connection=FALSE'
and added name to the BEGIN TRANSACTION, as follows:
            scommand="begin transaction tran1"
            execute immediate :scommand using object_tra

Answer (score 1):

From the PowerBuilder help on Autocommit:

When AutoCommit is set to True, you can use the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dynamic SQL statement to issue BEGIN TRANSACTION, COMMIT TRANSACTION, ROLLBACK TRANSACTION, and other SQL statements to control your own transaction processing. If you use the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dynamic SQL statement to issue BEGIN TRANSACTION, you must use the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dynamic SQL statement to issue a corresponding COMMIT TRANSACTION or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION.

This appears to be the relevant part: you must use the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dynamic SQL statement to issue a corresponding COMMIT TRANSACTION or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION.

Answer (score 0):

WE solved the issue yesterday using this:
We added this line to DBParm:
            ProviderString='MARS Connection=FALSE'
and added a name to the BEGIN TRANSACTION, as follows:
            scommand="begin transaction tran1"
            execute immediate :scommand using object_tran